# How to correct change state of object in vector?

Tags: c++

I came from Java world and currently in way to understand whole perfect world of C++.

I have written code, that simply has class `Test` with base operation, `getValue()` and `doOperation()` which have to change state of object

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
  Test (float v = 100.f) : _v (v) {}

  float getValue () { return _v;}

  void doOperation() {
      cout << "Before Operation " << _v << endl;
      _v = _v * 2;
      cout << "After Operation " << _v << endl;
  }

private:
  float _v;
};

int main ()
{
    vector<Test> tests;
    tests.push_back(Test ());
    tests.push_back(Test ());
    tests.push_back(Test ());
    tests.push_back(Test ());
    tests.push_back(Test ());   

    for (auto v : tests)
        v.doOperation();

    for (auto v : tests)
        cout << v.getValue() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So, I faced problem when I putted objects to vector and in `foreach` call the function `doOperation()` to change state of object, but the exactly state of object doesn't change after `foreach` function have ended. I didn't use pointers in vector, but when I rewrite code to use `vector<Test*>` it works fine

> So my question is, can I change state of object in `foreach` without pointers and why it's happen ?

Also link for code https://onlinegdb.com/H172qW7n4
And for the same code with pointers https://onlinegdb.com/Skze2-7hV

Comment: `auto v` makes a copy as usual. Use `auto &v` if you want a reference instead.

Comment: Also props for not littering the code with `new` as Java people coming to C++ incorrectly tend to do.

Comment: Note that `tests.emplace_back();` will add a default constructed instance of `Test` without having to explicitly make one yourself. Edit : I was confused about `push_back`.

Comment: `.push_back({})` works, but is probably inferior.